# Are there useful videos about Core Data?

Tags: iphone, core-data

I wonder if there are good videos out there that describe Core Data in detail, starting out with the basics?

I know nothing about Core Data. Would like to watch a few videos in addition to the hard-to-read apple docs. I'm reading all day now about core data and feel my brain hasn't gained much additional knowledge ;)

Please list all you know. Free and Paid. I want ti know all of them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you're an Apple Developer Connection Select member, you have access to some of the "foundational videos" from previous WWDCs.  Among these is the WWDC 2006 session "Core Data in a Nutshell", which was given by Apple to first introduce Core Data on the Mac, and is a great starting video on the subject.  There also is the WWDC 2007 session "Optimizing Your Core Data Application".

For the iPhone, if you're willing to spend the $299 for the WWDC 2009 iPhone track videos (which I highly recommend, given the amount of information there), there is the "Introduction to Core Data on iPhone" session.  That one session is about the best overview there is for Core Data in its iPhone incarnation.  Also in WWDC 2009 is the "What's New in Core Data" session highlighting some of the new additions to Core Data appearing first on the iPhone and in Snow Leopard.

I second Adrian's recommendation of the CocoaCast [episode on Core Data](http://cocoacast.com/?q=node/24).  It's what first caused me to look at Core Data on the Mac.

If you're looking for audio content, I'd recommend Marcus Zarra's walkthrough of Core Data in the [second episode of Late Night Cocoa](http://www.mac-developer-network.com/shows/podcasts/late-night-cocoa-002-core-data-with-marcus-zarra/).

UPDATE 7/8/2010:  The videos for my advanced iPhone development course are now [available on iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032), including one class on Core Data.

Comment: Nice1 on the core data video. Downloading now. :D