# Core Data Resources

Tags: iphone, core-data

Please give me some good resources based on Core Data...
Thanks.

Comment: Why dont you google for it and dont make others to search for you?

Comment: @Harry...i googled it and i am getting very elementary dummy applications...which i already constructed...by saying "resources"...
I meant good references from books or anywhere else...
But you take it light...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Starting point in learning Core Data on iPhone?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3164300/starting-point-in-learning-core-data-on-iphone)

Comment: See also: [Best ressources for learning Core Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2956841/best-ressources-for-learning-core-data) and [Are there useful videos about Core Data?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2059670/are-there-useful-videos-about-core-data)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@devaditya there is a core data tutorial in the devlopers document of X-Code and here it is **[coreDataBooks](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CoreDataBooks/Introduction/Intro.html)** and its a best one and also have a look on these....

http://www.bukisa.com/articles/180100_iphone-core-data-tutorial-part-1

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/iphone-core-data/